# getting hibernate.QueryException,

Tags: java, hibernate

Please let me know how to write the jpa query for following persistence class, as i have tried but getting exception.

```
 Criteria criteria = Criteria.forClass(Detail.class);
 criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("uid", "U001"));
  Detail det = (Detail) criteria.uniqueResult(getEntityManager());
```

Below is the persistence calss :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="detail")
public class Detail extends Test<Serializable>  {

    @EmbeddedId
    private DetailPK id;   // This is a class which holds primary keys

    @Column(name="price")
    private BigDecimal price;
    . . . . . . . 
)

public class DetailPK {
@Column(name="uid")
private String uid;
. . . . . . 
}
```

Comment: Why don't you post the exception?

Answer (score 1):

try,

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Detail.class).add(
                    Restrictions.eq("uid", "U001"));
            Detail det = (Detail) criteria.uniqueResult();
```